# Scikit-learn learning curves with different scorers and leave one group out cv yield same values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, svm

I want to plot learning curves on a trained SVM classifier, using different
scores, and using Leave One Group Out as the method of crossvalidation. I
thought I had it figured out, but two different scorers - 'f1_micro' and
'accuracy' - will yield identical values. I am confused, is that supposed
to be the case?

Here's my code (unfortunately I cannot share the data as it is not open):

```
from sklearn import svm
SVC_classifier_LOWO_VC0 = svm.SVC(cache_size=800, class_weight=None,
  coef0=0.0, decision_function_shape=None, degree=3, gamma=0.01,  
  kernel='rbf', max_iter=-1, probability=False, random_state=1, 
  shrinking=True, tol=0.001, verbose=False)
training_data = pd.read_csv('training_data.csv')
X = training_data.drop(['Groups', 'Targets'], axis=1).values
scaler = preprocessing.StandardScaler().fit(X)
X = scaler.transform(X)
y = training_data['Targets'].values
groups = training_data["Groups"].values
Fscorer = make_scorer(f1_score, average = 'micro')
logo = LeaveOneGroupOut()
parm_range0 = np.logspace(-2, 6, 9)
train_scores0, test_scores0 = validation_curve(SVC_classifier_LOWO_VC0, X,
  y, "C", parm_range0, cv =logo.split(X, y, groups=groups), scoring = Fscorer)
```

Now, from:

```
train_scores_mean0 = np.mean(train_scores0, axis=1)
train_scores_std0 = np.std(train_scores0, axis=1)
test_scores_mean0 = np.mean(test_scores0, axis=1)
test_scores_std0 = np.std(test_scores0, axis=1)
print test_scores_mean0
print np.amax(test_scores_mean0)
print  np.logspace(-2, 6, 9)[test_scores_mean0.argmax(axis=0)]
```

I get:

> [ 0.20257407  0.35551122  0.40791047  0.49887676  0.5021742
>   0.50030438
>     0.49426622  0.48066419  0.4868987 ]
>
> 0.502174200206
>
> 100.0

If I create a new classifier, but with the same parameters, and run
everything exactly as before, except for the scoring, e.g.:

```
parm_range1 = np.logspace(-2, 6, 9)
train_scores1, test_scores1 = validation_curve(SVC_classifier_LOWO_VC1, X,
y, "C", parm_range1, cv =logo.split(X, y, groups=groups), scoring =
'accuracy')
train_scores_mean1 = np.mean(train_scores1, axis=1)
train_scores_std1= np.std(train_scores1, axis=1)
test_scores_mean1 = np.mean(test_scores1, axis=1)
test_scores_std1 = np.std(test_scores1, axis=1)
print test_scores_mean1
print np.amax(test_scores_mean1)
print  np.logspace(-2, 6, 9)[test_scores_mean1.argmax(axis=0)]
```

I get exactly the same answer:

> [ 0.20257407  0.35551122  0.40791047  0.49887676  0.5021742
>   0.50030438
>     0.49426622  0.48066419  0.4868987 ]
>
> 0.502174200206
>
> 100.0

How is that possible, am I doing something wrong, or missing something?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show a self-contained example with sample data demonstrating the problem?  My guess is that one of your runs is accidentally re-using an already-defined variable from an earlier run, although I don't see where in the code you posted.

Comment: I will try but it would take me some time to figure out how to build a self-contained example that is meaningful as these features are wireline logs form wells, and targets are geological facies.

Comment: @BrenBarn  In the meantime, bearing in mind your suggestion, I will comb my full code again for re-used variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`F1 = accuracy` if and only if `TP = TN`, that is, the number of true positives equals the number of true negatives, which can happen if your classes are perfectly balanced. So it's either that, or you have an error in your code. Where do you initialize your scorer, as follows: `scorer = make_scorer(accuracy_score, average = 'micro')` ?

Comment: My accuracy scorer is initialized as: Ascorer = make_scorer(accuracy_score) but I get same issue wether I do that or not, and just pass 'accuracy' without initializing it. I will have to check on code errors. Classes are not perfectly balanced. Thanks